# Uber API "Get Products" endpoint returns different data than app.

Tags: uber-api

This is a question for the UBER dev team. I'm calling to the "Get Products" endpoint and I'm returning products for a list of cities. In some of the cities, the API returns that there are no products in the latitude/longitude pair but when I use the app I am able to request a ride in that city.

Ex, Meridian, MS:

```
{ lat: 32.3643098, lng: -88.703656 } { products: [], 
   rate_limit: { limit: '2000',
      remaining: '1979',
      reset: 2017-10-27T17:00:00.000Z } }
```

In app:
[Meridian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oezVT.png)

Is this intentional, or is this something that we can expect to be fixed in future releases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce. Calling GET for https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude=32.3643098&longitude=-88.703656 (the lat / long you specified) returns a product: [image: screenshot of postman showing product for that lat/long]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @Kyle!! I found my error.

Comment: Great, no problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

My error was that I was parsing and therefore rounding the latitudes and longitudes before I used them in the call to the endpoint, which gave me incorrect latitudes/longitudes to use.